# Powerpoint, Disable click to next slide but not animations

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I'm working on a presentation, I have a standard slide where you click to bring up bullet points on by one, however after all the bullet points have appeared I want the presenter to click one of two buttons to go to certain slides and do not want the next click to progress to the next slide.

I have tried disabling mouse click to advance on the transition options but that also disables triggering the animations.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First, set the presentation to Kiosk Mode (Slide Show | Set Up Show)

Next, add a rectangle that fills the slide, send it to back, format it to match the background or give it a 99% transparent fill so it disappears.

Select the text that's set to appear line by line and use the animation settings to have it Trigger on click of the rectangle you just inserted and sent to back.

Now when you click the slide (actually the rectangle), your text will appear, line by line. Kiosk mode will prevent the slide from advancing due to any random clicks, and your action button can advance to the next slide.

The only hitch I see to this is that repeated clicking will reveal all of the text lines then cycle back to none showing, then one then two etc.

Answer (score 2):

using Powerpoint 2016, i was able to accomplish what you're asking by selecting the transition tab at the top, and deselecting "On Mouse Click" in the Advance Slide pane...

now if you accidentally click on the screen (not one of the buttons) it will not jump to the next slide.

Comment: Did you succeed in still having other elements appear on the slide, click by click?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question fully however its too long for a comment...

You need to create Action Buttons (draw a box, click on it and go to Insert on Ribbon).

In this section you can select hyperlink to... Slide... and select what slide the button should go to..

Does that help?

Comment: That part is already setup.  its if the user clicks elsewhere instead of the button that is a problem

Comment: Oh I see, so if you go the slide with the buttons on. Click outside of any object so just on the white space and go to transitions > Advance Slide > Untick 'On Mouse Click'... that seems to work here...

Comment: Sorry just read your question it disbables the animations...

Comment: So what slide is the animation on the slide your going too or the slide the buttons are on?

Comment: Animations seem to work ok for me with buttons setup this way...

Comment: as a test case, slide 1, 3 bullet points, each one comes up after a single click, there is also a button on slide 1 that takes the user to slide 3, if once the 3 bullet points have appeared the user clicks the page in general they will go to slide 2, the part where they can go to slide2 is the issue, we want slide transitions to stop but without disabling animations

Comment: Can you add the buttons as part of the 'Fade in' with the bullet points. So turn off the mouse click to transition > have your 3 bullet points fade in > fade the buttons in on the last click after the bullet points and then the presenter can progress? hope that makes sense

Comment: Unfortunately not, got a workaround in place with transparent pngs capturing future clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a "no-fill" shape the size of the slide. I brought it to the front and hyperlinked it back to the same slide.
Next, I brought the buttons for the forwarding to the front.
So far the only downside I have found is that the cursor is always displaying the Pointing Hand.

Answer (score 0):

I always display a small curved arrow to indicate that I have to click in order to advance to the next animation.

I gave to each arrow of the same slide the name "anim_01", "anim_02" etc.

I link each animation, apart the first one, to each "anim_0x".

The only problem I find is that I am forced to click on the arrow and not in any place.